# Extra column created in db while using Hibernate OnetoOne Bidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, one-to-one, hibernate-onetomany

I am practicing Hibernate and I am getting the data populated in the db but there is an extra column that is being added along with the JoinColumn

Entities:
Mobile Class-

```
@Entity
public class Mobile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer mobileId;
    
    @Basic
    private String mobileName;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Sim sim;
    
    public Mobile() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Mobile(Integer mobileId, String mobileName, Sim sim) {
        super();
        this.mobileId = mobileId;
        this.mobileName = mobileName;
        this.sim = sim;
    }
    public Integer getMobileId() {
        return mobileId;
    }
    public void setMobileId(Integer mobileId) {
        this.mobileId = mobileId;
    }
    public String getMobileName() {
        return mobileName;
    }
    public void setMobileName(String mobileName) {
        this.mobileName = mobileName;
    }
    public Sim getSim() {
        return sim;
    }
    public void setSim(Sim sim) {
        this.sim = sim;
    }
}
```

Sim Class-
@Entity
public class Sim {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer simId;

@Column(name="name")
private String simName;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "mobile")
private Mobile mobile;

public Sim() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Sim(Integer simId, String simName, Mobile mobile) {
    super();
    this.simId = simId;
    this.simName = simName;
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public Integer getSimId() {
    return simId;
}

public void setSimId(Integer simId) {
    this.simId = simId;
}

public String getSimName() {
    return simName;
}

public void setSimName(String simName) {
    this.simName = simName;
}

public Mobile getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(Mobile mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}
```

}

```
Main Class-
```

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

```
    Mobile mobile = new Mobile();
    mobile.setMobileName("Nokia");
    Sim sim = new Sim();
    sim.setSimName("Aircel");
    mobile.setSim(sim);
    sim.setMobile(mobile);
    
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.save(mobile);
    
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

}

```
Output:
mobile table:

    mobileId|mobileName|sim_simId|
    --------+----------+---------+
           2|Nokia     |        2|

sim table:

    simId|name  |mobile_mobileId|mobile|
    -----+------+---------------+------+
        2|Aircel|               |     2|



Why is the column mobile_mobileId being generated?
```

Comment: Hello, most probably the column `mobile_mobileId` has been created by Hibernate before you made a change and added the annotation with join column name `mobile`. If you let Hibernate drob and re-create database it will go.

Comment: BTW: you can get rid of the column in the table Sim if you add attribute mappedBy as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you haven't used mappedBy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).